# I want the position of the bottom div to be below the top div

Tags: css, flexbox

I want the bottom div to change its position relative to the top div. Bottom div's position should be bottom of top div. But instead bottom div is is not do anything. How can i achieve it?

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ju8q8UtZJc)

I want the bottom div to change its position relative to the top div. But instead bottom div is is not do anything. How can i achieve it?

```html
<div className={styles.topContainer}>
  <img className={styles.leftImage} src={imageURL + details?.poster_path} />
  <img className={styles.rightImage} src={allImages[0]} />
</div>

<div className={styles.bottomContainer}>
  <div className={styles.genres}><Genre genres={genreList} /></div>
  <p className={styles.overview}>{details.overview}</p>
</div>
```

```
.topContainer {
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.leftImage {
    min-width: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;  
    align-items: center;
}

.rightImage {
    margin-left: 20px;
    min-width: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;  
    align-items: center;
}

.bottomContainer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Can you give the HTML code as well?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as a closing  `</img>` tag. Also, you are inconsistent in how you use `<img>`. The [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob Aaah yes you are right. I missed that point thanks for specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-order: 1` to the one you want to be on top and `flex-order: 2` to the one you want to be on bottom. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property)

Answer (score 0):

On decreasing the screen size, the image gets smaller but the parent div has fixed height (as you're giving fixed height to topContainer). You want to move the bottom div upwards when the top div gets smaller in height. I think this can be achieved by setting the height of "topContainer" to "fit-content".

```
.topContainer {
height: fit-content;
}
```

Please note that in this case, you might need to set the height of images as well, because the parent has no height now, instead relying on its children's height.